# Расширение для FireFox, меняющее элемент

Tags: javascript, firefox

Пытаюсь написать расширение, для FF. Расширение, должно менять некий элемент на сайте.

chrome.manifest

```
content     vkstats    chrome/content/    
content     vkstats    chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes    
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://vkstats/content/browser.xul
```

content/browser.xul

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <overlay id="vkstats" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://vkstats/content/main.js" />  </overlay>
```

content/main.js

```
var VKStats = {

    init: function () {
        /////////////////////////
        var l_ap = document.getElementById('l_ap');
        var l_stats = document.createElement('li');
        l_stats.innerHTML = 'Тест';
        insertAfter(l_stats, l_ap);
    },

    getUserId: function () {

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", "http://vk.com/", false);
        http.send();
        var user_id = /"user_id":(\d+)/m;
        return user_id.exec(http.responseText)[1];
    }

};

function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
    return refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
}
```

Вроде, как расширение включается, только при запуске браузера, но не добавляется элемент. Если, добавить в JS код, например alert(111);, отработает, только один раз при старте браузера в независимости, на каком сайте вкладка. Даже если обновлять страницу, все равно alert не отработает.

Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема?

```
var VKStats = {
  init: function(){
    if(gBrowser)
            gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent){
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc that triggered the event
    var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
    /////////////////////////
    var l_ap = doc.getElementById('l_ap');
    var l_stats = doc.createElement('li');  
        l_stats.innerHTML = 'тут текст';
        //l_ap.appendChild(l_stats);
        insertAfter(l_stats, l_ap);
  },

  getUserId: function(){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET","http://vk.com/",false);
    http.send();
    var user_id = /"user_id":(\d+)/m;
    return user_id.exec(http.responseText)[1];
    }

};

function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
    return refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
    VKstats.init();  
},false);
```

Comment: @or_die: (там комментарии кончились) проверьте регулярное выражение, наверняка проблема в нём. Например, `(..)?` выглядит подозрительно. Вставьте временный `alert(doc.location.href)` _перед_ `if`'ом.

Comment: ни чего не выводит.

Comment: @or_die: заработало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто: ваш инициализатор и правда исполняется только один раз, это для всех расширений так. Вам надо подписаться на событие загрузки страницы (например, `DOMContentLoaded`) и в нём уж делать то, что вам необходимо.

[Код](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load):

```
var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        if(gBrowser)
            gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // document that triggered the event
        var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        // тут делайте что вам надо
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); // нужно только 1 раз
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

Comment: а потом, обращаться как doc.getElementById('l_ap'); ?

Comment: @or_die: потом `doc` -- это ваш документ. Обращаться `doc.getElementById('l_ap')` можно, но есть ли в нём такой `id`, вопрос случая. Код будет вызван для _всех_ страниц.

Comment: не работает, даже alert не вызывается

Comment: @or_die: пишите ваш изменённый код: телепатия пока не мой конёк. На досуге подумайте, что вернёт `getElementById`, если элемента нету на странице, и что это значит для вашего кода.

Comment: обновил первый пост

Comment: @or_die: всё-таки моя телепатия сработала. Подумайте сами: вы пытаетесь вставить новый элемент на **каждой** странице. И как поведёт себя функция `insertAfter`, если в качестве `refElem` получит `null`? (И ещё, в вашем коде нету `alert`'а.)

Comment: @or_die: (1) проверяйте, на какой странице сработал скрипт. Не пытайтесь обработать все страницы: расширение же не должно работать на google.com? (2) проверяйте результат `getElementById` и завершайте работу скрипта, если он не такой, как надо. (3) вы на 100% уверены, что всегда найдётся `parentNode` и `nextSibling`?

Comment: 1 parentNode и nextSibling всегда найдутся
2 getElementById проверять на undefined ?
3 Пытаюсь обробатывать так onPageLoad: function(){
if (!doc.location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(..)?vk.com(\/.)?$/i) && !doc.location.href.match(/^https:\/\/(..)?vk.com(\/.)?$/i) ) return;
alert('aaaaa');
на сайте vk.com алерт не выпригивает